# Unable to correct "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, html

having python code:
....

```py
def DisplayTable(filename):
    #dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    fullFilename = dir+'/Data/'+str(filename)
    data = pd.read_csv(fullFilename, header=None)
    data=data.iloc[:: -1]
    print(data)
    stringList = [str(x) for x in data] 
    print(stringList)
    #data= tuple(data)
    headings=(" ", "Date", " ", "Temps")
    return render_template('fDetailTemps.html',  data=data, headings=headings)`
```

My HTML gives the error:  `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I have tried several solutions found on this board, but none have helped (latest trial is in above code using `str(x)`.)
the `print(data)` statement gives:

```
4    Date:   2021-Dec-20, 04:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.56
3    Date:   2021-Dec-20, 03:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.79
2    Date:   2021-Dec-20, 02:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.79
1    Date:   2021-Dec-20, 01:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.90
0    Date:   2021-Dec-20, 00:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.79
```

and the `print(string_list)` gives:

```py
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

portion of the HTML code:

```html
       <table>
        <tr>
           {% for header in headings %}
              <th>{{ header }} </th>
           {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for row in data %}
           <tr>
               {% for cell in row %}
                  <td> {{ cell }} </td>
               {% endfor %}
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `for cell in row` inside of your HTML.

`for row in data` makes `row` the integer 0 or 1 or 2...etc and because of that `for cell in row` makes no sense as row is an integer not a list to iterate over.

Comment: TY - it did eliminate the int error message, but, it shows no data at all. I was supposed to remove the whole    {% for cell in row %}   <td> {{ cell }} </td>   {% endfor %} ? I tried with and without removing the {{ cell }} portion

Comment: try `return render_template('fDetailTemps.html',  data=data.iterrows(), headings=headings)`

Comment: and inside HTML `%for index,row in data%`

Comment: this will make `row` the corresponding line for the `index` for example the index 0 will have the following row: `Date:   2021-Dec-20, 00:00       Kombucha Temp:   77.79`

Comment: Almost? The headings are correct now, but data not showing. This is what I now have in HTML:         <tr>
           {% for header in headings %}    <th>{{ header }} </th>
           {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for index,row in data %}
           <tr>
               <td> {{ cell }} </td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: change `cell` to be `row` now.

Comment: So I now get data, but it has additional info (this is one of many rows): 0 Date: 1 2021-Dec-26, 23:00 2 Kombucha Temp: 3 76.89 Name: 167, dtype: object